# Как проверить является ли значение текстом в jQuery

Tags: jquery

Вечер добрый, такой вопрос, есть поле инпут с классом (example) предположим. 
В этом инпуте должны быть только цифры, как можно сделать так, что бы если пользователь вводит туда буквы, значение этого инпута выставлялось "0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципиальном плане так:

1. накиньте на инпут событие с отслеживанием изменений (при фокусе на нем желательно): [Событие .change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)
2. Вариант 1: отфильтруйте клавиши/вводимые символы и соответственно фильтруйте от ненужных простыми if/else приблизительно так: [Пример как отслеживать клавишу "shift"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479307/how-can-i-detect-shift-key-down-in-javascript)
   Вариант 2: получите значение value у инпута вот так:

   `var input_text = $(element).val();`

   и фильтруйте все например через регулярные выражения.

   `input_text = input_text.replace(/[^\d]/g, "0");`
3. если совпадений нет то просто задаете

   `$(element).val('0');`

Comment: br3t ваша правка несомненно улучшает сообщение, я нажал принять, однако я рекомендую в будущем предварительно связываться с автором ответа, чтобы внести правки, которые потенциально могут не совпадать с исходной мыслью автора (я не про форматирование кода, а про добавление кода: в этом конкретном случае вероятно угадали, но лучше этим стараться не злоупотреблять)

Comment: @AK , хорошо, принято

Answer (score 0):

Может лучше запретить ввод текста, используйте autonumeric

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.